# PM2 status stopped : exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

Tags: reactjs, deployment, pm2

I have a React app and 2 .env files, .env.prod and .env.dev, first one I use for reaching production APIs, and the other one for development APIs. When I start my app I do it with react run start:dev or react run start:prod depending on which APIs I want to fetch.

I started playing with PM2 and wanted to start the app in the background with it but I always get an error like the title above. My ecosystem.json:

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "dev_eronet",
    "script"      : "./src/app.js",
    "watch"       : true,
    "args": "serve build port=3000",
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "dev"
    },
    "env_production" : {
       "NODE_ENV": "prod"
    }
  }]
}
```

environments folder:

[image]

the command in the terminal that I use:
`pm2 start ecosystem.json --env prod`

pm2 logs:
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem but I couldn't solve it. Did you get the solution?